# Cyrillic symbols make a mistake in SQL Server 2017 with R

Tags: sql, r, sql-server, t-sql, encoding

I am using SQL Server machine learning and R Services (In-Database) and trying to make a request from script to get [Номенклатура ЕКТУ Подгруппа4] column:

```
 EXEC sp_execute_external_script
   @language = N'R',
   @script= N'
    library("magrittr")
    library("RevoScaleR")

    sqlQuery <- "SELECT TOP(15) [Номенклатура ЕКТУ Подгруппа4] FROM dbo.data"
    print(sqlQuery)
    # Load extra data from local SQL Server 
    conStr2 <- "Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=localhost;Database=Transactions;UID=*****;PWD=*****;"
    ds <- RxSqlServerData(sqlQuery=sqlQuery, connectionString=conStr2)

    rxImport(inData = ds) -> OutputDataSet

   '
   , @input_data_1 = N'SELECT * FROM [CarsTech].[dbo].[vehicles]'
   , @input_data_1_name = N'Cars'
   WITH RESULT SETS (( [Value] numeric not null, [Name] varchar(15) not null, [Trans] varchar(25) not null));
```

As a result I got the errors after applying rxImport:

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Íåäîïóñòèìîå èìÿ ñòîëáöà "ÐÐ¾Ð¼ÐµÐ½ÐºÐ»Ð°ÑÑÑÐ° ÐÐÐ¢Ð£ ÐÐ¾Ð´Ð³ÑÑÐ¿Ð¿Ð°4".
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Íå óäàëîñü âûïîëíèòü ïîäãîòîâêó èíñòðóêöèé.
```

Something wrong with Cyrillic symbols when passing  [Номенклатура ЕКТУ Подгруппа4]. I've already tried to use UTF-8, cp1251 and so on. It did not help

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the Cyrillic symbols as unicode with `N''`:

```
EXEC sp_execute_external_script
 @language = N'R',
 @script= N'
 library("magrittr")
 library("RevoScaleR")

 sqlQuery <- "SELECT TOP(15) N''[Номенклатура ЕКТУ Подгруппа4]'' FROM dbo.data"
 print(sqlQuery)
 # Load extra data from local SQL Server 
 conStr2 <- "Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=localhost;Database=Transactions;UID=*****;PWD=*****;"
 ds <- RxSqlServerData(sqlQuery=sqlQuery, connectionString=conStr2)

 rxImport(inData = ds) -> OutputDataSet

'
, @input_data_1 = N'SELECT * FROM [CarsTech].[dbo].[vehicles]'
, @input_data_1_name = N'Cars'
WITH RESULT SETS (( [Value] numeric not null, [Name] varchar(15) not null, [Trans] varchar(25) not null));
```

Comment: The mistake dissapeared. But It does not work, I got only a vector of m elements filled with: [Номенклатура ЕКТУ Подгруппа4], [Номенклатура ЕКТУ Подгруппа4], [Номенклатура ЕКТУ Подгруппа4] ....